# Android Sqlite framework

Tags: android, database, frameworks, android-sqlite

I am searching for a flexible SQLlite framework for android.
I was able to find ORMlite.

My Question: are there any other frameworks ?

Comment: you may work with sqlite frameworks in java. (if any exists)

Comment: A framework to do what?

Comment: a framework to create,edit,update,delete a db, but flexible enough to accept almost any objects. Something like ORMLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use ORMlite for Android. I think is the most lightweight and robust but you can give it a try to greenDAO, check this:
http://greendao-orm.com/

Also you have Object DBs, like neodatis or db4o. But my recommendation is to stay with SQLite and a good ORM framework like ORMLite.

If you need to look at the DB structure in Eclipse you can install the Questoid plugin:

http://www.questoid.com/

Comment: Using ORMLite, are there any issues obfuscating the code ?
I saw that ORMLite is using reflection, and from my previous experience with obfuscation I need to add -keepclasses due to reflection.
I'm concerned that sensitive data will not be obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid). I haven't try it yet, but it looks pretty simple and clean according to its documentation.